# docker-cloud repository query doesn't provide a response

Tags: docker, docker-cloud

I'm trying to query docker-cloud repository using this command

`docker-cloud repository ls`

I get this response.

`NAME    IN_USE`

My repos are located here and have active images
https://hub.docker.com/r/fellfromhell/workshop-python/

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the exact command you're trying?

Comment: my mistake, I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 different systems: Docker Hub and Docker Cloud.
[Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/) is a cloud-based registry. [Docker Cloud](https://cloud.docker.com/) is a service which helps to deploy and manage Dockerized applications. You can link Docker Cloud to repositories hosted on a third party registry. The Docker Hub registry is linked automatically and all your Docker Hub repositories are listed in https://cloud.docker.com/_/repository/list, but, unfortunately, the command

```
docker-cloud repository ls
```

returns only repositories that are on a third party registries (see 
https://docs.docker.com/apidocs/docker-cloud/#external-repository).
Despite this, you still can inspect your image

```
docker-cloud repository inspect fellfromhell/workshop-python
```

and get some data in response. Here is the github issue https://github.com/docker/dockercloud-cli/issues/23